# Why do Zombies eat plants in "Plants vs. Zombies"?

Tags: video-games, zombie, plants-vs-zombies

AFAIK, Zombies aren't vegetarians. They usually have a special interest in eating living human brains. Why do they eat the Plants then?

Comment: With their mouths.

Comment: They all have eyes, so it stands to reason they have brains too.

Comment: But the part about magic plants (powered by tiny suns emitted by mutant sunflowers) shooting various blasts at zombies doesn't raise any concerns for you?

Comment: Would you agree to change the question from "How" to "Why"? I think that would make much more sense.

Comment: Not sure why there are so many downvotes; this isn't a bad question.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I thought all they wanted to do was eat your brains, they aren't unreasonable, I mean, no one's going to eat your eyes.

Comment: They decide to become Jain...LOL

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17543/2565

Answer (score 47, accepted):

from [popcap *Plants vs. Zombies* readme](http://www.popcap.com/games/plants-vs-zombies/pc/readme#PG/ZO) :

> Nobody knows exactly what eldritch force or demented science allowed the dead to rise from their graves and walk. What we do know is that the resulting creature, popularly termed a "Zombie," is a restless, mindless, tireless being driven by nothing other than its hunger for brains. **Your brains, to be precise.**
>
> **In order to get those brains, zombies are willing to chew through any plants in their way.** Though slow, zombies are persistent, and if even a single zombie gets past your defenses and into your house, he will eat your brains.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you don't have to be neither a vegetarian or a vegan to eat plants. Vegetarians are people who merely do not eat meat. Omnivores eat everything (well, a diversity of things).

In the universe of the game, the plants *defend* the precious brain of the person(s) in the house. The game's zombies show a basic intelligence (contrary to the classic Romero/Brooks Zombie). This leaves us with two possibilities.

### First

The zombies don't actually eat the plants -- they just try to destroy them as they seem to block their path (this explanation would not work for the digger-zombie, though, but maybe the digger-zombies **are** vegetarians and want to help their carnivore friends get some brain, but that's a hell of a stretch).

### Second

They are fine eating plants as long as they are supplied but they start eating brains when the plant supply runs low. This would mean they're true omnivores.

Answer (score 6):

The Zombies aren't interested in the Plants, really. They want to eat **your** brains. You're planting the Plants in order to prevent the Zombies from getting in your house. The Zombies say as much in their many Notes they send you between levels, and when they mutter "Brainz...." every so often.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason why the zombies eat the plants is because the plants themselves have brains. As evidenced by that one time Zomboss threatens to eat the plant brains in PvZ 3. That would explain why the zombies target the sentient plants and not the boring ones. (trees, bushes, grass, ect.)

Comment: Could you [edit] in the relevant quote to back this up?