# Why do digger-zombies walk in the wrong direction after emerging from the ground?

Tags: video-games, zombie, plants-vs-zombies

We [have learned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17515/2565) that the zombies in *Plants vs. Zombies* eat our precious plants because they hinder their way to get into the house. So the zombies themselves have no interest in eating the plants as such.

This raises the question, why digger-zombies:

[image: a single digger zombie facing the wrong direction (they never look left when standing)]

would start walking away from our house as soon as they reach the last line. They've arrived just where they wanted to go.

This how it looks after they reach the "finish line":

[image: a horde of digger zombies]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [Plants vs Zombies wikia](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Digger_Zombie)

> Note that as it eats the plants from left to right, it never makes an attempt to get into the homeowner's house. **This may be because when they stand up, their eyes are rolling so they may be confused and feel dizzy.**

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic misunderstanding of Natural Selection. It is not individuals that drive the evolution of a species, it is the community that does. This is why it is desirable for bees to kill themselves with stings in the name of a hive.

The Zombies are becoming the new dominant species on the planet, and it makes sense that there would be a primitive yet sophisticated social order amongst them. The digger zombies exemplify this spirit perfectly by sacrificing their own potential gain in the name of assisting the population at large.

They are the Zombie equivalent to our own heroes that sacrifice their health and lives so that others may live.

Comment: But, Zombies don't work in teams...

Comment: At least, bees have brain..

Comment: I see two fundamental problems with your assessment. The first is that by no means zombies are subject to Natural Selection, as they do not procreate in this fashion -- at least not the classical Romero zombie. A successful zombie will by no means influence the success of any other zombie. However this is not true for the Brooks zombie, where zombies infect living humans thereby creating family trees, granted.

Comment: Still, more problematic is that altruism is by no means agreed to work in the fashion you describe. Species selection is most likely not applicable (your bees example can still be explained by selfish individual bees), as selection is driven by genes. Since zombies have never been observed to care for "family" members (even in universes where zombification is a natural, not a mythical process), there is no way you can argue they would sacrifice themselves to allow closely related genes to survive. I still like your approach, though :)

Comment: @bitmask we don't know if/how Zombies can procreate other than infection. And the genes I refer to are ones present in us. They are still genetic organisms and altruism is seen in all levels of animals. And populations evolve, not individuals. Anything that helps the population, promotes those genes, which most members of a group share. That's how altruism evolved. Zombies just express it in their hosts.

Comment: @DampeS8N: The most classic zombie (Romero) works not by viral infection (although personally, I prefer the infectious Romero-zombie) but simply because the bite or scratch of a zombie poisons the victim (the same infection you would get if you were actually bitten by a corpse) which proves fatal. Everybody who dies, rises. Therefore, if I'm bitten by zombie XY, there will be nothing that connects us afterwards. Thus, XY sacrificing himself for me would not help to select his genetic (zombie/human) content. Thus, altruism stands no chance of getting selected. Zombies must be entirely egoistic.

Comment: @bitmask But it would help zombie survival as a whole. And we aren't exactly sure how PvZ zombies work. So infection through bites may be required. Therefore, if your prey starves to death in their home successfully defending against you, your viral load won't be passed on. Your viral strain will go extinct.

Answer (score 3):

Digger-Zombies come out from ground in rotating-jump fashion. Unfortunately, after landing their direction become opposite (thanks to physics engine). As they don't have brain to think, they don't turn around and end up in heading towards wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather sweet version of the zombies.
Digger zombie,"I dug through the soil, and I have reached the safety, and the brain is right in front of me. But then I see, my friends taking the burden of the heavy enemy fire,  dying on their path. So I turned, I am determined, I will salvage all of you from this burden, my friend. This is a stupid act, but I had no brain to think it over, so through danger I go, on this path where I might miss my goal forever."

Comment: Hello and welcome to the SE. Quick note: this would be better as a comment since it is not an answer. I'd suggest looking at the Tour under the help menu above. Hint: since reading the Tour gives you a badge, and you have no badges, it's obvious you have not read it.

Comment: @MeatTrademark: Unless it's a quote from an official source. Ming, did you make up the quote or can you offer a link where it came from?

Comment: Using Google to search for phrases in his post (in quotes of course) only return hits for this post. Just one hit. I'd guess it's not an official quote given that evidence.